# TFS 2010 Backup fails with "The current username failed to retrieve MSSQL Server service account. "

Tags: sql, tfs, backup

I am trying to backup my **TFS 2010** instance using the **TFS 2010 Power Tools** issued in March 2011.

In the verification step, I am getting an error that I do not know how to solve:

**"The current username failed to retrieve MSSQL Server service account."**

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you running SQL Express and/or running SQL Server service as Local Service?

Comment: We are running SQL Server as a Local Service.  TFS, SQL and our domain server is all on one VM. We are a small office with 4 developers so performance is great, but unfortunately we can't get the backup working.

Comment: Try moving to a named account (good practice anyway).  There is a known bug with applying permissions to Local Server which is likely causing the problem.

Comment: Ryan -- Thanks for the suggestion... What permissions do I need to give the named account.  I am worried about making a change that causes TFS to stop working...  (right now I back up by shutting down the server and taking a copy of the VM in the morning before the developers start, which works, but is a pain)

Comment: It's conventient that this is a VM, because you can try this and restore a snapshot if it does not work.  The SQL Server Configuration manager will do most of the account configuration you need.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx.  The exception that I can think of is access to mdf files if they aren't located in the default Data directory for the SQL instance.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that has sorted it. I posted the complete process as an answer, but never would have got there without your assistance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer, in my instance, required a few things:

1. As Ryan noted in the comments above, the SQL service account cannot be "Local System". Create a new user account on your domain, and then follow the instructions Ryan provided: [Setting Up Windows Service Accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx).
2. Change the service account for TFS from Local System to a service account on your domain. I followed these instructions: [Change the Service Account or Password for Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552178.aspx).
3. To configure the backup, log on using the same account as was used originally to install the TFS server instance. (I'm not sure what permissions are missing from my other administrator account)

Comment: It's also important to have a backup path with no spaces or underscores!