# Error "TF400998: The current user failed to retrieve the SQL Server service account information" when trying to configure backup plan in TFS 2012

Tags: sql-server, tfs, backup

I'm at a loss with trying to find a solution to this issue.  When I am trying to create a backup plan in TFS 2012 I get "TF400998: The current user failed to retrieve the SQL Server service account information. Please make sure you have permissions to retrieve this information."

My TFS server and SQL server are on separate VM's on the same domain.  I login to my TFS server with my domain account which has admin rights to the machine which is also the same account I setup TFS with initially.  I connect to my SQL server using my local machine using the same domain account and that account is in the sysadmin role.  Everything seems to be working fine except for this.  All the information I have read seems to point to the SQL service account being a local account, but I'm using my domain account for everything.  Below is a link the closet post to some real answers, but I've tried everything I can think of, please help!  Thank you!

[TFS 2010 Backup fails with "The current username failed to retrieve MSSQL Server service account. "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262962/tfs-2010-backup-fails-with-the-current-username-failed-to-retrieve-mssql-server)

Answer (score 0):

So I found that you have to check several things.

- List item

Run TFS admin tool with the service account credentials or login to the server with the TFS service account.

- List item
  Make sure all your database names are [TFSServerName. Assuming it's installed on the current server. Mine were defaulted to longer domain names... like ServerName.xya.ado.com  I changed it just ServerName

After it worked fine.