# TF400998 error attempting to restore TFS databases from one server to another

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am attempting to move TFS from SERVERA to SERVERB.  I am using this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869(v=vs.110).aspx) as my main resource for accomplishing this.  I have installed SQL Server (same version) on SERVERB.  I have backed up the SERVERA TFS databases.  I installed TFS but did not configure on SERVERB.  On SERVERB, I used the TFS admin console and clicked restore databases and navigated to the network location of my backup.  After selecting the backup set there are a few more screens to go past but eventually I get the below error during the readiness check.  I am logged in as a domain user who has local administrator rights (in the local administrators group).  I believe that if I can solve the TF400998 error the other errors (TF246017) may go away as well.  The error refers to "The current user".  If that means my domain user, then what exactly is the restore looking for?

[image]

Edit: I will rephrase my question.  Since my domain account is a powerful user on the system, what permission might be missing?  Also, this account has the sysadmin server role in SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE** as SQL Server service account and have a try. Also see the below threads to solve the issue:

- [TFS 2010 Backup fails with "The current username failed to retrieve MSSQL Server service account. "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262962/tfs-2010-backup-fails-with-the-current-username-failed-to-retrieve-mssql-server)
- [Backup plan wizard generates an error](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a72d59c2-57cd-4016-87ba-26ce287e4e7a/backup-plan-wizard-generates-an-error?forum=tfspowertools)

Comment: I changed the service accounts from a local user "SQLUser" to your suggestion "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE ".  I get the same exact error.  I am now tracking down you other suggestions from the links provided.  The first link "TFS 2010 Backup fails..." seems to suggest using a domain account.  I need to get with IT folks for this.